# What if(event) statement means in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm rather new to JavaScript and programming in general so I am pretty much only used to seeing if statements that have some kind of comparison operator like, `if (x < 10)` or `if(myBool)`.

I have seen an `if` statement checking against an `event`, but I don't understand what or why the `event` is being checked like that.  What's the semantic meaning behind that check or comparison?

Here is the code in question:

```
if(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: tried reading some tutorials lately?

Answer (score 5):

Javascript has a feature called *type coercion*. There's a nice [reference/tutorial for booleans here](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/), so I'll not go into detail as to what gets type-coerced to what. A common shorthand for casting to a boolean from any type of `myVariable` is to boolean-negate it twice: `!!myVariable`.

Objects (which is what a javascript event usually is) evaluate to `true` if they're non-`null` and non-`undefined`. Empty objects (with `length === 0`) also evaluate to `true`.

Boolean operators short-circuit evaluation, meaning that it's common to shorthand one-line if-blocks like this:

```
event && event.preventDefault();
```

---

Functions can also be type coerced into boolean `true`s. This is a valid piece of javascript:

```
if(event.preventDefault) { // Note if event is undefined this WILL throw an error
    event.preventDefault();
}
// or, avoiding the error
if(event && event.preventDefault) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

The code snippet you posted can commonly be seen in event handlers, though it's usually unnecessary: an event propagator is probably breaking contract if it's passing an undefined event handle to the handler. (And if that is a valid contract, it's probably bad design)

Comment: `0` evaluates to false as well (and yes, is an object - for example: `0..toExponential(3)`)

Comment: @Izkata Actually it's a primitive `number`. Calling `0.0.toExponential(3)` (or any property/method) autoboxes it to a `Number` object. A `Number` object with value 0 (or `new Number(0)`), unlike a primitive, converts to a `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what `event` is we cannot really say much, other than that by the end of the day, `event` resolves to either `true` or `false`. In the above, the code is most likely checking that `event` is not `null`.

Comment: "`if(event)` is the same as `if(event == true)`" no, this is not correct.

Comment: "`if(!event)` is the same as `if(event == false)`" is also not correct

Comment: @zzzzBov: Yes you are right, removed.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has the concept of "truthy" and "falsy" values.

The following values are `falsey`:

- `false`
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `0`
- `NaN`
- `''` (empty string)

All other values are `truthy`.

When a variable is cast to a boolean its "truthiness" is checked. When evaluated in an `if` statement, or any of `?:`, `||`, and `&&`, the variable is automatically cast to a boolean for the purposes of the check (the variable itself isn't changed).

What this means is that:

```
if (event) {
```

is essentially treated as:

```
if (Boolean(event)) {
```

This sort of check is often used to verify that a variable exists before using methods on it. In this case it prevents a null reference error on undefined variables.

---

**Note:** Truthiness is ***not*** the same as checking a variable against `true` or `false`.

I.E.

```
if (foo) {
```

is not the same as

```
if (foo == true) {
```

A simple example of where this fails is when comparing against an object:

```
var foo = {};
if (foo) {
    console.log('this works!');
}
if (foo == true) {
    console.log('this doesn\'t work!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This means event is either non-zero (if it's value is integer), true (if it's a Boolean) or non-null (if it's something else).

In many languages (compiled or scripting), when a condition is evaluated, it results in a value. Thus, x < 10 results in true (or in some languages a non-zero numeric value), and then it is interpreted as a true condition. Thus, if you were to say if(event) where event's value was 1 (or non-null), then it would be considered true and the if block will be executed. The same logic applies to null vs non-null.

You can try this JS code and see that one alert will go up and the other won't. You can replace event with null vs a string (e.g. 'blah') as well as a 0 vs non-0 and see that it will behave similarly:

```
var event = true;
if (event) alert('true!');
var event = false;
if (event) alert('false!');
```